# Passing values between web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to pass a dollar amount from one webpageto another webpage without letting the user modify the values when the values are passed between these pages.
ie Page 1 (entry page) to Page 2 (confirmation page)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948805/how-can-i-send-an-array-of-strings-from-one-asp-net-page-to-another/2948836#2948836

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the value into the `Session` and retrieve it from the second page.

Comment: Agreed. In request 1 (entry page) Keep the amount in session variable, so that it's persistent among request. In request 2 (confirmation page), display it, and delete it afterwards.

It's often called "flash message".
http://blog.agilephp.com/2008/06/03/flash-messages/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try on view state if the data is not so critical.

Comment: Viewstate is valid for page itself. On redirection it is lost